# ctr always undefined in function <reactjs>

Tags: reactjs

```
<script type="text/jsx"> 
    var Counter = React.createClass({
      ChangeValue: function(ctr){
      alert(this.state.arr[ctr]);
        this.setState({
          arr : this.state.arr[5]
        });
      },
      getInitialState: function(){
         return {
           arr:[
           '0','0','0',
           '0','0','0',
           '0','0','0'
           ],

           arr2:[
           0,0,0,
           0,0,0,
           0,0,0]
         }
      },
      render: function(){
        var sese = [];
        var ctr = 0;
        sese.push( <h1>Count: {this.state.arr}</h1>)
        for(var i = 0; i < 3 ; i++)
        {
            for(var j = 0 ; j< 3 ; j++)
            {
                sese.push(<button type="button" key={ctr} id={ctr} onClick={this.ChangeValue.bind(null, this.ctr)}>{this.state.arr2[ctr]}</button>)
                ctr = ctr + 1;
            }

            sese.push(<br/>)
        }
        return (

            <div>{sese}</div>

        );
      }
    });

    ReactDOM.render(
        <Counter/>, 
        document.getElementById('root')
    );
</script>
```

i tried this

```
var Counter = React.createClass({
      ChangeValue: function(ctr){
      alert(this.state.arr[this.ctr]);
        this.setState({
          arr : this.state.arr[5]
        });
      },
```

and still undefined..
i'm studying react , get stucked with my ctr in alert , and don't know the solution..
i'm trying to change the value of my button. if i click the button, the value will become 1 but my ctr is always undefined. does anyone know why my alert is always undefined?

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on what you're trying to do here, but if you pass `ctr` then I don't think you need `this` - in other words, it should be `this.state.arr[ctr]`. What do you get if you `console.log(this.state)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `onClick` you have to pass just `ctr` and not `this.ctr` as it does not exist.

```
onClick={this.ChangeValue.bind(null, ctr)}
```